How is 今の (ima no) / 今のは (ima no wa) formed grammatically?
I understand the usage and the meaning is obvious, however I want to know how it is actually formed. The meaning makes sense as "of now" for eg. in this funny clip:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLt5qSm9U80
@ 0:21 , "でも今の日本語だったよね？”　, "but that was Japanese just then, right?" This is clearly casual speech so 今のは　is shortened to 今の and conveys the same meaning.
However I am confused,
is 今の formed with the の particle acting as a possessive particle? Or is it formed with the の particle acting as a nominalizer?
For eg. の acting as the possessive particle in 私の本 , "My Book". Or even 今の所 , "now's present"
Or as a nominalizer in サッカーを するの 　が/は 好きです。 ”I like playing soccer." Same with 今のは...

今 is not a verb and can already be used as a noun. That information should tell you what you need to know

Good point. So の is acting as the possessive particle, right?
